# Access values of parse url

Tags: php

I have this array that I would like to get the value of 1 out and save it as a variable. How do I do that?

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => pianotunerpros.com
    [path] => /techportal/profile/
    [query] => 1
)
```

Here is the code I use to get that

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

print_r(parse_url(curPageURL()));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: You might wanna give this a quick read, http://www.php.net/manual/en/introduction.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be data from a call to parse_url. If all you care about is the query portion of the url you can avoid creating the array at all by calling

```
$query = parse_url($url,  PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

otherwise

```
$query = $array['query'];
```

will work.

If you are looking for the name of the array key that has the value of 1 you can use array_search

```
$test = array_search(1, $array);
```

Comment: All I care about is the query portion, but I can't seem to figure out how to get your first part to work, how do I get the url to put into it

Comment: how are you creating the array in the above example?

Comment: sorry I missed the code update

Comment: I just removed the function around the code and I was able to get the url

Answer (score 5):

You can access THE array elements using The key:

```
 $value = $array['query'];
```

Comment: Sorry for THE in caps, iPad is not good for coding php

Answer (score 1):

not sure what do you mean by 'the value of 1'. assuming it was the value in 'query'

```
$value = $parsedURl["query"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access it easily like this :-

```
$s='http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=2&number2=200';
$str=parse_url($s);
echo $str[query];
```